# iTunes downloading movie faster over WiFi

Tags: itunes, wifi, thunderbolt, ethernet

For some reason iTunes will download a movie faster over wifi than with ethernet on my home network. When I do a speed test the ethernet connection appears to be a few mbps faster though... Why would it download slower on ethernet? (I turn wifi off when using ethernet via the thunderbolt adapter)

Comment: Various reasons. Probably, your ethernet might be more obstructed and clogged

Comment: But then shouldn't the speed test be slower on Ethernet, not faster as it is?

Comment: it might just vary, a few mbps is nothing. Could be that over the Wi-Fi connection it is performing more requests per second but a speed test might run at a different rate

Comment: It seems to take about ten minutes longer to download over Ethernet which is significant

Comment: movies are very large so small differences can get more significant. A megabit is only 0.0001 of a Gigabyte

Comment: The file is about 4.7 GB, it takes iTunes ~25 minutes over wifi and ~35 over Ethernet...  That's more substantial than a couple Mbps

Comment: @Buscar웃SD the Ethernet is connected to the same router as the wifi comes from

Comment: The speed test is a 64 bit file. The movie download is much larger packets thus those 2 can not be used as comparison. Your speed test is correct, cable is always faster than WiFi. Your Ethernet connection has problems with large packets. That should be the router problem. Try different sockets or reset the router.

Comment: The fact that you say the Ethernet was only slightly faster in speed test indicates you have a bad cable (probably Cat5) which goes up to 1 Gb/s, since with Cat6 cable you can get 10 Gb/s.

Comment: @Buscar웃SD that only matters if my internet speed is 1gbps or more...

Comment: @Buscar웃SD and my wifi is AC, Internet speed is 50Mbps

Comment: Than your speed test should have been significantly faster with Ethernet cable (up to a maximum of your provider speed). Did you check the MTU settings for both connections.

Comment: My Ethernet retuned 48Mbps and the Wifi was 46Mbps

Comment: It is not possible for WiFi to be faster than cable. The iTunes has nothing to do with either (it does not knows where the Network comes from). Your cable and/or your router needs some attention if it is truly slower than WiFi in downloading.

Answer (score -1):

I know what your trying to ask here. When you do you speed test are you downloading the movie at the same time? If yes then the mbps will consistently change so when your over wifi and when your switching back to ethernet. If your were not downloading a movie when doing the speed test there is the difference already, when toe downloading something it using more data that means if more people are using the Internet as well then it will consistently change again.

To put it into a perspective, image your router has 20 (whatever of 20). Your wife logs on 20 goes to her then you log on splits 10 & 10 then you have let's say your friend over now it's uneven so your each getting 6.6 from the router. You see how it keeps getting smaller so there are so many factors that play in to make it better with Ethernet or better wirelessly.

Comment: I understand how networking works, I'm the only one on the network, and it's a fiber optic connection to my ISP. The issue is unless the Ethernet cable is bad it should not be slower than wifi which has more bandwidth issues inherently. I am not downloading while doing the speed test, of course downloading would make the test appear slower.

Comment: But the thing is, if the Ethernet cable were bad, why would it have a faster connection than the wifi according to speed test

Comment: I see hmmm you have a good question I am not sure :/ sorry I couldn't have helped :(